# Триггер в SQL

Tags: sql

Я все мучаюсь с триггером(

Есть две колонки с датами, сначала нужно рассчитать с помощью триггера разность в днях между этими датами и записать в колонку разность, а потом от 30 отнять получившееся число и записать в остаток...

как только уже не пробовал, разность всегда работала, а остаток только первый вычислялся...как должны update располагаться?

```
alter trigger dlina ON Holiday

FOR INSERT,UPDATE  AS

declare @KolvoDays int

declare @OstatokOtpuska int

UPDATE Table1

set KolvoDays=DATEDIFF(DAY,Table1.StartDate,Table1.FinishedDate),

    @KolvoDays=Table1.KolvoDays

    UPDATE Table1

    set Ostatok=28-@KolvoDays

from Table1,inserted

where Table1.NumID=Table1.NumID
```

Answer (score 1):

что-то я не уверен, что присвоение значения переменной  @KolvoDays=Table1.KolvoDays в update корректно